# Can't create an index on a jsonb field with date

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, database-indexes

I have a jsonb column `event` in a table. I am trying to create an index

```
CREATE INDEX ON table(((events->'START'->> 'date')::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST'));
```

but it is throwing error `functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

After passing it a timezone it should make it immutable, but I am not sure why it's still throwing an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL create index on cast from string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405602/postgresql-create-index-on-cast-from-string-to-date)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757374/

Answer (score 1):

The cast to `timestamp` is your problem. It is not `IMMUTABLE` because the function used accepts arguments like `now`.

If you are certain that your data contain only regular timestamps and no such values, you can define your own `IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql` function that wraps the type cast.

You can use such a function in your query and index it. If there are values for which the cast truly isn't immutable, your index will become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Augmenting Laurenz Albe's answer with my own to be able to post code, I'm using the following.

Assuming you have a table `mytable` with JSONB field `thedata`, which contains data like `{ "datetime": "2020-03-21T33:44:55.193843281Z ", ... }`:

```sql
-- Create immutable UTC parsing function, see:
-- * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877503/cant-create-an-index-on-a-jsonb-field-with-date
-- * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973030/error-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-immutable-in-postgres
-- It parses dates of format:
--     YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
-- (with a 'T' between date and time, and a 'Z' at the end) for example:
--     2020-03-21T33:44:55Z
--     2020-03-21T33:44:55.193843281Z

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utc_to_timestamp(some_time text)
  RETURNS timestamp with time zone
AS
$BODY$
    select to_timestamp($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"');
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

-- Define the index:
CREATE INDEX mytable_expr_datetime on mytable (utc_to_timestamp(the_data ->> 'datetime'));
```

So for the table/field names in your question, you have to replace `the_data ->> 'datetime'` by `events->'START'->> 'date'`, and `mytable` by `events`.