# String to numerical in Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a `flask` application tied to a `postgres` db. I am filtering table `Stock` like following,

```
Stock.query.filter(Stock.availablequantity < Stock.minimumquantity)
```

**The problem:**
I see wrong outputs like **23** is less than **5**!!

`availablequantity` and `minimumquantity` are saved as string in db (and I can not change this for other reasons) and I don't know how to convert these quantities in the query itself.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the columns' [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=cast#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.cast) method to cast (convert) to the type that you want in the query.

```py
# from db import Integer may work in flask-sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer

Stock.query.filter(Stock.availablequantity.cast(Integer) < Stock.minimumquantity.cast(Integer))
```

This will generate this SQL:

```sql
SELECT stock.id AS stock_id, stock.availablequantity AS stock_availablequantity, stock.minimumquantity AS stock_minimumquantity 
FROM stock 
WHERE CAST(stock.availablequantity AS INTEGER) < CAST(stock.minimumquantity AS INTEGER)
```

This isn't very efficient: if this query is being run frequently on a large table then changing the column types in the database will be a better solution.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16405935/5320906) describes a way to get better performance (though indexing in the database) when dealing with queries over different types - it's about comparing strings and dates but the approach should be similar for integers.